# AWS ecs create-service "Invalid JSON received" error even with file:// syntax

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I'm trying to create a service using the AWS CLI from JSON, but I keep getting `Invalid JSON received` even with the `file://` syntax. I generated the skeleton for the JSON with `--generate-cli-skeleton`.

`aws ecs create-service --cli-input-json file://test-app.json`

`test-app.json` is in the current working directory. Here is the content:

```
{
  "cluster": "wf-development",
  "serviceName": "test-app-2",
  "taskDefinition": "xxxxxxxxx",
  "loadBalancers": [
    {
      "targetGroupArn": "xxxxxxxxx",
      "containerName": "test-app",
      "containerPort": 80
    }
  ],
  "serviceRegistries": [],
  "desiredCount": 1,
  "launchType": "EC2",
  "role": "AWSServiceRoleForECS",
  "deploymentConfiguration": {
    "maximumPercent": 200,
    "minimumHealthyPercent": 100
  },
  "placementConstraints": [],
  "placementStrategy": [],
  "healthCheckGracePeriodSeconds": 10,
  "schedulingStrategy": "REPLICA",
  "enableECSManagedTags": true,
  "propagateTags": "NONE",
  "enableExecuteCommand": true
}
```

I'm new to AWS and just figuring this out, but I did this yesterday on a different PC and it worked just fine.

Edit: I'm using Windows and Powershell.

Comment: you have not mentioned your OS. I will assume Linux, and you can use jq to check if your JSON is really valid or not. if it is not, jq will tell the part that is not valid

Comment: @SharuzzamanAhmatRaslan Sorry I'm in Windows using Powershell. I know the JSON is valid.

Comment: highly likely mixup of newlines. aws cli skeleton is highly likely output Unix type text file, and you edit it in Windows type editor (eg notepad) which does not understand Unix text file. try edit your file using Notepad++ or VS Code which understand Unix text file. reference: jsonlint.com: Different Results If you use a Windows computer you may end up with different results. This is possibly due to the way Windows handles newlines. Essentially, if you have just newline characters (\n) in your JSON and paste it into JSONLint from a Windows computer, it may validate it as valid errorneously

Comment: @SharuzzamanAhmatRaslan My text editor can change the line ending mode and I tried both Windows and Linux and it still gives the error.

Comment: then the only option left is to install jq in Windows, and run test against your JSON file: https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/

Comment: @SharuzzamanAhmatRaslan How would that fix anything? I can see in my text editor that the JSON is perfectly valid.

Comment: @SharuzzamanAhmatRaslan Yes, jq validates it correctly as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, very strange. I just copied the contents of my JSON file into a new file without changing anything and it works now.